# Restored database from .bkp file in SQL Server 2014 generates some strange errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, ssms, intellisense

I have restored the well-known [Northwind database](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) and executed a trivial query:

[image]

Notice the strange error "Invalid object name..." although the query has been executed successfully and both tables can be seen in Object Explorer.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Try switching your current database to the Northwind one. Intellisense will sometimes take a bit to catch up and cache objects. Turning it off and then on again sometimes helps me, but if something runs I don't usually sweat the red underlines.

Comment: Type Ctrl+Shift+R. This is just a warning that the editor can't see the object; it doesn't mean the object doesn't exist. It's probably just not loaded by IntelliSense yet (and sometimes it can take a long time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors have nothing to do with the fact that the database is restored (in fact they aren't even errors, just intellisense being flaky).

As you can see in the dropdown top left and the status bar (in yellow) you are executing your query against the master database.

Either change your database in the dropdown or execute a `USE mydatabasename;`.

As noted by Aaron Ctrl-shift-R refreshes the intellisense but that could take a while before taking effect.